# Rails scan for forward slash

Tags: ruby

I am looking to find forward slash tags in posts to my website. How can I use `scan` in Rails to do this? This should get the `/` then the words following. For instance it would be `"This is my message /slash"` and I am looking to scan for `/slash`.

```
@forward_slashes ||= message.scan( )
```

Comment: to clear things up I am trying to get the equivalent to twitters #hashtag but I am using a /forwardslash instead. Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't see Rails here. *deleted tag*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on your question, as it's in broken English.  I think you're just referring to the ruby String method method scan - nothing rails-specific about it.

It just takes a regular expression.  /(\/.*)/ will match from the first forward slash to the end of the string.

my_string.scan(/\/.*/) {|slash_stuff| puts slash_stuff}

edit: using \w+ will only return the first word after the slash.  .* will return everything until the end of the string.

edit: using split will break it up into >2 pieces if there are multiple forward slashes, which isn't clear from your description what you would want for an input of hi / there / person - do you want "/ there / person" (use scan) or " there " and " person" (use split)

Comment: This works but I have a problem. If a link is inputted in my input field it also detects the rest of that string. Is there any way to detect the /slashtag with out detecting a link. I am also using this regular expression to link the posts when they are displayed. I may be confusing here. The user inputs this is my post /slashtag and here is a http://link.com .. I want both to be linked but when I used gsub to link the /slashtag it also screws up the original link.

Answer (score 1):

```
message.scan /\/\w+/ #=> ["/slash"]
```

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
"This is my message /slash".split('/')
```